# number of surjective functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Let $A, B$ sets, $|A| = n, |B| = r,~ 1 \le r \le n$.

Prove that there are $\displaystyle \sum_{k_1 + \cdots + k_r =~n \atop k_1,\ldots,k_r \in \mathbb N}  \frac{n!}{k_1! \cdots k_r!}$ surjective functions $f: A \rightarrow B$.

I know about the Stirling numbers of the second kind to solve this problem, but I don't know how to arrange the upper formula with or without the Stirling numbers.

I would be grateful for advice. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle \sum_{k_1 + \cdots + k_r =~n \atop k_1,\ldots,k_r \in \mathbb N}  \binom{n}{k_1}  \binom{n-k_1}{k_2}\cdots \binom{n-k_1\cdots -k_{r-1}}{k_r}=\displaystyle \sum_{k_1 + \cdots + k_r =~n \atop k_1,\ldots,k_r \in \mathbb N}  \frac{n!}{k_1! \cdots k_r!}$

Fix an order of elements of $B$. Select $k_1$ elements in $A$ map to $b_1$, then $k_2$ elements map to $b_2$ from remaining $n-k_1$ elements. Repeat.

Sum over all possibilities.