# $\sum\binom{n}{a_1}\prod\limits_{p=2}^{k}\binom{n-a_{p-1}}{a_p-a_{p-1}}=k!{n+1\brace k+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, combinations, stirling-numbers

We have
$$\sum\limits_{0\leqslant a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_k<n}\binom{n}{a_1}\prod\limits_{p=2}^{k}\binom{n-a_{p-1}}{a_p-a_{p-1}}=k!{n+1\brace k+1}$$
where instead of $\{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_k\}$ we place all possible combinations of $\{0,1,2,\cdots,n-1\}$ without repetitions, for ex. $n=4, k=3$, so all possible combinations are
$$\{0,1,2\},\{0,1,3\}, \{0,2,3\}, \{1,2,3\}$$
then
$$\binom{4}{0}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}+\binom{4}{0}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}+\binom{4}{0}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1}+\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}=60=3!{5\brace 4}$$

How can we prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 
$${n+1\brace k+1}k!={n\brace k}k!+{n\brace k+1}(k+1)k!={n\brace k}k!+{n\brace k+1}(k+1)!,$$
Recall that $k!{n\brace k}$ counts the number of surjective functions from $[k]$ to $[n]$ The left hand side is basically saying choose $a_1$ from $n,$ so that $1$ is send to them then choose $a_2-a_1$ from $n-a_1$ that $2$ will be send to. Etc. At the end of the process there is two options, either you finish selecting all of them or they had left. If they were left, then those are gonna be the image of $k+1.$

Comment: English not my native, so I don't completely understand your answer. In any case, thank you!

Comment: Mine neither. Ahh do you understand that ${n\brace k}k!+{n\brace k+1}(k+1)!$ counts the number of surjective functions from $[k]$ to $[n]$ and from $[k+1]$ to $[n]$? If yes, then check that the left hand side is picking the numbers of the codomain that will be send by the i-th element. Let me know(Se habla espagnol).

Comment: Well, after a long time I completely understand surjection and find a solution based on yours. Can I ask you how can you be sure that the left hand side is picking the numbers of the codomain that will be send by the i-th element? I mean how is it obvious for you?

Comment: Well, i have played a lot with Stirling numbers but i guess the answer to that would be that $\binom{n}{k_1}\binom{n-k_1}{k_2}\cdots \binom{n-k_1-\dots -k_t}{k_{t+1}}$ always  means picking secuentially to form an ordered partition(A surjective function.)

Comment: Sorry for my English again (and also my math mind). What you saying just now and this thing (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/990691) are the same or not?

Comment: I mean how you came to ordered partitions from combinations without repetitions? It's absolutely another type of sum.

Comment: Do not worry, basically yes. Cause a partition is a bunch of blocks, you have to pick the elements in the blocks. It can not have repetition otherwise it would not be a partition. It is the same concept iff you, at the end, picked all of them.

Comment: I want to say that $\sum\limits_{0\leqslant a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_k<n}\binom{n}{a_1}\prod\limits_{p=2}^{k}\binom{n-a_{p-1}}{a_p-a_{p-1}}=\sum\limits_{0\leqslant a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_k<n}\frac{n!}{a_1!(n-a_k)!}\prod\limits_{p=2}^{k}\frac{1}{(a_p-a_{p-1})!}$. Then we need to work with $2$ types of combinations: $a_1=0$ and $a_1>0$. For each type we also group them by $a_k=m$, $0<m<n$, because set $\{a_1, a_2-a_1, a_3-a_2,\cdots,m-a_{k-1}\}$ based on each such group of combinations is exactly each possible ordered partitions (but for $a_1=0$ it has $k-1$ elements instead of $k$ for $a_1>0$).

Comment: So we have for $a_1>0$: $f(n,k)=\sum\limits_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}\sum\limits_{b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_k=m}\prod\limits_{p=1}^{k}\frac{1}{b_p!}=\sum\limits_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}\frac{k!}{m!}{m\brace k}=k!\sum\limits_{m=k}^{n-1}\binom{n}{m}{m\brace k}=(k+1)!{n\brace k+1}$. Similar for $a_1=0$: $f(n,k-1)=(k)!{n\brace k}$. Summing them gives us result. So do we really need all those steps? I'm trying to understand your arguments, but because of factor $(n-a_k)!$ it doesn't look so easy.